# Crash on Androind signal 11 SIGSEGV, code 1 SEGV_MAPERR (Unity 5.6.0f3)

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine

I'm developing the game on Unity 5.6.0f3 and I'm facing the problem with some Android devices. This crash reproduces not on every android device, but on soma of them, like this: LG Optimus L7II, LG Magna, LG Leon, Lenovo A680, Lenovo P780, Lenovo S580, Lenovo A3300, Lenovo S850, Lenovo A2010-a, ZenFone 5 (A502CG), ZenPad C 7.0 (Z170CG), HUAWEI Y3II, HUAWEI Y635-L01.

This crash occurs when my app is in background. This is it:

```
Caused by java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), 
fault addr 000000f0
Build fingerprint: 'Huawei/Y635-L01/hwY635:4.4.4/HuaweiY635-
L01/C21B131:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 25582, tid: 25635, name: Thread-2988  >>> com.rmg.farmclicker <<<
r0 00000000  r1 6c0b30bb  r2 696e5500  r3 00000055
r4 622fa90d  r5 622fabf0  r6 622fa91d  r7 00000000
r8 622fa91d  r9 00010668  sl 622fa90d  fp 62a61b24
ip ffffffe8  sp 62a61880  lr 617d4e0c  pc 617d4c50  cpsr 2d353336

   at libunity.004d6c50(Unknown Source)
   at libunity.000d7064(Unknown Source)
   at libunity.000d8510(Unknown Source)
   at libunity.00312fe8(Unknown Source)
   at libunity.005ed0c4(Unknown Source)
   at libdvm.dvmPlatformInvoke(dvmPlatformInvoke:112)
   at libdvm.dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)(dvmCallJNIMethod:398)
   at libdvm.00029aa0(Unknown Source)
   at libdvm.dvmMterpStd(Thread*)(dvmMterpStd:76)
   at libdvm.dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)(dvmInterpret:184)
   at libdvm.dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)(dvmCallMethodV:336)
   at libdvm.dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)(dvmCallMethod:20)
   at libdvm.00058463(Unknown Source)
   at libc.__thread_entry(__thread_entry:44)
   at libc.pthread_create(pthread_create:316)
```

I'm using some native libs on C++ in my app and I thing that problem is in them.

I think that code can be the main problem:

```
#elif ANDROID
struct timespec res;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);

std::chrono::milliseconds uptime = std::chrono::milliseconds(static_cast<unsigned long long>(res.tv_sec) * 1000ULL + static_cast<unsigned long long>(res.tv_nsec)/1000000ULL);
return uptime.count();
```

So please help if you know something about it, thank you;)